# Typescript compiler not found

Tags: typescript, npm, visual-studio-code, tsc

> I tried to compile *index.ts* file using **tsc index.ts** in VScode terminal
> but terminal returns this

tsc : The term 'tsc' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- tsc index.ts
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (tsc:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

> I tried to set the path but i cant find,
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\0.8.0.0  its missing
> and Typescript is installed on   user/appdata/roaming/npm.....

**Updated**
I tried some of the solutions mentioned in similar problems but didn't worked for me so out of frustration i uninstalled node,TS and VS and reinstalled them (i know sounds desperate) but worked for me ....

Comment: Did you install typescript as a local dependency or globally with the -g flag?

Comment: If locally try running it with `npx tsc index.ts` while in the project folder.

Comment: I installed it globally by "npm install -g typescript"

Comment: @uranshishko i reinstalled node and typescript and now its working, THANKS for asking though.

Comment: Nice! No problem :)